# Create new column with some logic to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need to add a new column "price" based on an external table vprices.

I tried adding it as in the example, but I got an error because inside the parenthesis df["vol-type"] is a Series variable, not the nth value of the serie, which is what I need.

How can that be rewritten to get the new column "real_size" populated using the values of each row?

```
virtsizes = {
  "type1": { "gb": 1.2, "xxx": 0, "yyy": 30 },
  "type2": { "gb": 1.5, "xxx": 2, "yyy": 20  },
  "type3": { "gb": 2.3, "xxx": 0.1, "yyy": 10  },
}
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(src),names=["vol-id","size","vol-type"])

df["real_size"] = df["size"] * ( virtsizes[df["vol-type"]]["gb"]
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is `src` ?

Comment: just a string with a csv

Answer (score 1):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by row of `df1` selected by `loc`:

```
virtsizes = {
  "type1": { "gb": 1.2, "xxx": 0, "yyy": 30 },
  "type2": { "gb": 1.5, "xxx": 2, "yyy": 20  },
  "type3": { "gb": 2.3, "xxx": 0.1, "yyy": 10  },
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(virtsizes)
print (df1)
     type1  type2  type3
gb     1.2    1.5    2.3
xxx    0.0    2.0    0.1
yyy   30.0   20.0   10.0

df = pd.DataFrame({'vol-type':['type1','type2']})

df["real_size"] = df["vol-type"].map(df1.loc['gb'])
print (df)
  vol-type  real_size
0    type1        1.2
1    type2        1.5
```

Another solution is extract `gb` in `dict comprehension`:

```
virtsizes = {
  "type1": { "gb": 1.2, "xxx": 0, "yyy": 30 },
  "type2": { "gb": 1.5, "xxx": 2, "yyy": 20  },
  "type3": { "gb": 2.3, "xxx": 0.1, "yyy": 10  },
}
d = {k:v['gb'] for k,v in virtsizes.items()}
print (d)
{'type2': 1.5, 'type1': 1.2, 'type3': 2.3}

df = pd.DataFrame({'vol-type':['type1','type2']})
df["real_size"] = df["vol-type"].map(d)
print (df)
  vol-type  real_size
0    type1        1.2
1    type2        1.5
```

Comment: Really nice. didn't know about this. I found a different way, but this is way nicier.

Comment: Thank you. In pandas is the best avoid loops, so `iterrows` is used only very rare.

Answer (score 0):

Not as niciest as jezrael one, but this also works:

```
real_size = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  real_size.append(row["size"] * virtsizes[["vol-type"]]["gb"])
df["real_size"] = real_size
```